# How to write a script that compiles all SCSS files to CSS in Vue 3?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

In my project, there is a file called index.scss in the src/assets/styles folder. At the same level, there are multiple folders containing SCSS files that are ultimately imported into index.scss. I want to create a script in the package.json file that compiles all SCSS files and places them in the src/assets/styles/css folder.

"scripts": {
...
"compile": "node-sass --watch src/assets/styles/ -o src/assets/css",
}

In one of my files, I include the normalize library:

`@import 'node_modules/normalize-scss/sass/normalize';  @include normalize();`

Displays such an error:
`{ "status": 1, "file": "C:/work/flowers-box/node_modules/normalize-scss/sass/normalize/_vertical-rhythm.scss", "line": 15, "column": 17, "message": "Invalid CSS after \"...   @return math\": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was \".div($value, $base-\"", "formatted": "Error: Invalid CSS after \"...   @return math\": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was \".div($value, $base-\"\n        on line 15 of node_modules/normalize-scss/sass/normalize/_vertical-rhythm.scss\n        from line 2 of node_modules/normalize-scss/sass/_normalize.scss\n        from line 1 of src/assets/styles/common/normalize.scss\n        from line 2 of src/assets/styles/index.scss\n>>     @return math.div($value, $base-font-size) * 1rem;\n\n   ----------------^\n" }`

I tried removing these 2 lines, and it worked. How can I make this file compile as well, or completely ignore it during compilation?

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting an error, then add it to the question. You can also call the command directly from command-line to get more verbose information. You may need to replace `node-sass` with `./node_modules/.bin/node-sass`

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use `node-sass` which has been deprecated years ago?

Comment: In one of my files, I include the normalize library:
`@import 'node_modules/normalize-scss/sass/normalize';
@include normalize();
`
I tried removing these 2 lines, and it worked. How can I make this file compile as well, or completely ignore it during compilation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SassError: Invalid CSS expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67195466/sasserror-invalid-css-expected-expression-e-g-1px-bold) I think you should replace `node-sass`  as mentioned by @EricMORAND - see the [Install Sass documentation](https://sass-lang.com/install/)

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering is related to the normalize library's SCSS file, specifically the _vertical-rhythm.scss file. The issue seems to be with a line that includes a mixin or function that's not being parsed correctly by the SCSS compiler.

To resolve this, you have a couple of options:

1. Exclude the normalize Folder from Compilation
   In your script, you can modify it to exclude the normalize folder from the compilation process. You can do this by using the --exclude flag with node-sass:

   "scripts": {
   "compile": "node-sass --watch src/assets/styles/ --output src/assets/css
   --exclude src/assets/styles/normalize"
   }

This modification should prevent the SCSS files inside the normalize folder from being compiled.

2. Use a Separate Compilation Process for normalize
   If you want to include the normalize styles in your project but avoid the compilation issues, consider creating a separate compilation process for the normalize library. You can do this by creating a separate SCSS file specifically for normalize and then compiling it separately from your main SCSS files.

Create a new SCSS file for normalize (e.g., normalize.scss):

```
// normalize.scss
@import 'node_modules/normalize-scss/sass/normalize';
@include normalize();
```

Modify your compilation script:

```
"scripts": {
  "compile": "node-sass --watch src/assets/styles/ --output src/assets/css --exclude src/assets/styles/normalize",
  "compile:normalize": "node-sass src/assets/styles/normalize.scss --output src/assets/css"
}
```

Run the compilation script for normalize separately:

```
npm run compile:normalize
```

This approach allows you to handle the normalize styles separately from your main styles, avoiding potential conflicts during compilation.

Choose the approach that best fits your project structure and requirements. If the issue persists, you may also want to check for updates to the normalize-scss library or consider alternative normalization solutions.